# Searching for files within specific folder

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

Hello I got a question regarding finding files with a batch file.
I have the following Batch file:

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
set arg3=%3

echo %arg1% %arg2% %arg3%

for /r %arg1% %%g in (%arg3%) do echo %%g
```

The lay-out of my folders are:

```
TEST
---- 1702
-------jquery.js
---- 1704
-------jquery.js
```

Whenever I run the batch file with this input:

```
test.bat "C:\Batch Examples\TestDir" "C:\Batch Examples\OutDir" "jquery.js"
```

I get the following output:

```
"C:\Batch Examples\TestDir" "C:\Batch Examples\OutDir" "jquery.js"
C:\Batch Examples\TestDir\"jquery.js"
C:\Batch Examples\TestDir\1702\"jquery.js"
C:\Batch Examples\TestDir\1704\"jquery.js"
```

Why is `C:\Batch Examples\TestDir\"jquery.js"` shown in the result?
There is no jquery file within the TestDir directory.

The desired output that I want is:

```
jquery.js
jquery.js
```

anyone can explain to me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fault is to use a fixed value for arg3. `For /R` will iterate the (sub)folders starting from arg1 applying "jquery.js" for each folder, it doesn't evaluate.

```
@Echo off
echo %1 %2 %3
for /r "%~1" %%g in ("%~3*") do echo %%~fg
```

Should return:

```
C:\Batch Examples\TestDir\1702\jquery.js
C:\Batch Examples\TestDir\1704\jquery.js
```